# Where should I manage advanced algorithms/services on the server side in my project structure?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, architecture, application-design

I'm working with nodejs, expressjs, mongodb and angular with RESTful API.

Here is my project structure.

```
-- config
-- models
-- public
---- css
---- js
------ controllers
------ services
---- views
-- routes          // API route
```

Everything was ok because my API calls were simple and most of the logic is managed by angular with services.

But now I have to implement advanced algorithms and some logic server side and I don't know where to do it.

Should I add another *services* folder server side? How would you manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your application. Since you application has a node.js backend. and you want to implement advanced algorithms, it should be on the server side. Its always wise to keep the front-end light as possible because you don't want the user to be waiting.

Keep some weight on the back-end, but again it all depends on what type of application you are talking about. All your advanced algorithms should be written in the Controllers or the .js files.

Example server side structure for a shopping cart application :
[image]

Note how the **categories.js**, **product.js**, **models.js**, **api.js** are broken down to.

**In summary:** 
If your advanced algorithms comes in pricing of a product in reference to the example shopping cart application, its better to write it in the product.js and if its related to sorting categories, or showing categories according to user, then better write that logic in the category.js. This will be handy for the existing and a new developer coming into the application. Remember, organized applications are fun to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would recommend that you add a *services* folder that holds server-side js files that do some biz, and those files could be in turn organized according to your biz models, for example you can have `services/products.js` that handles some biz operations on the `products` collection/table.

In turn you can inject those files into your controllers/routes using something like

`var productsBiz = require('./services/products.js');`

and use that `productsBiz` by calling any of its exposed members.

BTW, I see some other folks out there do those biz stuff by adding custom functions on the db models themselves, that would be a good idea but that is logically valid only for functions related to this specific db model, for example doing some custom validation or altering values before saving, but for biz related to the whole app and not specifically for a db model, for example handling orders which will involve several db models like products, orders, shipping, invoices, etc., in such case I recommend doing such biz in a `services/*file*.js`.